# How to show time in minutes.seconds.milliseconds on jqPlot Line chart x-axis

Tags: charts, jqplot

We have a local webserver which collects data from hardware and another web based app that shows the data on a line chart using JqPlot. Data fetch is done through Ajax.

I wish to show multiple data series on line chart, all having same xaxis values (the time value). The xaxis should be able to show time in minutes.seconds.milliseconds.

I have tried regular lineAxesRenderer, which is good, but shows only upto 1 decimal point, i.e. 25.1 to 25.2. If we have data that changes mutliple times within 100ms, we get different Y values for the same x value. This makes the graph look jagged, when actually we are getting different values for different time stamps.

I have also tried DateAxisRenderer, however in that case...the call to replot() to change the axis before redraw() simply fails. The x-axis data I am sending to the client is "H:M:S.MS" format. My options for x-axis are as follows:

```
xaxis : {
   label : "Time (s)",
   show : true,
   renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
   rendererOptions : {tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer},
   tickOptions: {formatString: "%H:%M:%S.%N"},
   tickInterval:'500', // javascript timestamps are in milliseconds
},
```

What am i doing wrong here?

How do i show 2 or 3 decimal places on the x-axis if I use simple lineAxisRenderer?

Thanks and best regards,
Vishal

Comment: Can you post an example of your data?

Comment: Hi Ian,
Heres an example of my data. Each data point is x,y where x is time in seconds and y is sin value.

Comment: (58.382387813331974, 0.0)
(58.4321794771115, 0.4363101609320878)
(58.48218555935888, 0.8724874175625242)
(58.53218702217787, 1.3083989060735959)
(58.58218271071137, 1.7439118436031324)
(58.63218879295876, 2.1788935686914543)
(58.68218409653989, 2.6132115816913366)
(58.73220480697718, 3.046733585128687)
(58.7821901017968, 3.479327524001636)
(58.832200803472574, 3.910861626005772)
(58.88220996533889, 4.341204441673258)
(58.93221874225283, 4.77022488441362)
(58.98215283840777, 5.197792270443983)
(59.03221704846242, 5.623776358596625)
(59.08216038347415, 6.048047389991694)